# Saleor Migrations Failed(django.db.utils.DataError)

Tags: saleor

I am using a Saleor app that is running. I'm only using the API, but when I set the Saleor dashboard and try to run it again, I get this error:

```
sudo docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate
        Creating saleor-forstok_api_run ... done
        Operations to perform:
          Apply all migrations: account, app, auth, bank, checkout, contenttypes, core, csv, discount, django_prices_openexchangerates, django_prices_vatlayer, giftcard, invoice, menu, order, page, payment, plugins, product, shipping, site, sites, warehouse, webhook, wishlist, xendit
        Running migrations:
          Applying checkout.0023_checkout_country...Traceback (most recent call last):
    
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
        psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(2)
        
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
        res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
        post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
        state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
        schema_editor.add_field(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
        self.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

Comment: sorry it solve, it related to shipping country

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: changing the model so insted of 2 change the length of record and check if the record is more than two it gives warning in def clean or def save.